# CSS Transform not animating when class is added programatically (but works if I toggle the class in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am trying to animate the transform of a div.

Here is my code (for now, consider only the latest Safari for simplicity, which doesn't require vendor prefixes):

```
#mydiv{
    transition: all 2.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: scale(0.5);
    background:white;
    padding:30px;
}
.visible-popup{
    transform: scale(1)  !important;
}
```

My div doesn't have `visible-popup` class initially, and I'm using jQuery's `addClass` method to add it. However, My div jumps to 100% scale without animating. Interestingly, if I toggle the `transform` property of `visible-popup` class in Chrome's developer tools manually, or if I just manipulate the DOM in inspector and add/remove the class by hand, it *does* animate perfectly. Why isn't it animating when I toggle the class programatically?

Comment: I know in jquery you should use on() or bind(). maybe a relation to this?

Comment: @dmaij I don't understand how those are related to CSS transitions? could you please provide a resource about it?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough to css transitions te be regarded as expert. I meant to say that when adding an element programatically, the events from jquery must be bound afterward. Css should not have this 'problem', but it might point you in the direction you are looking for. or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. `#mydiv`'s container div had a class named `fade` which apparently didn't have any effect at all. When I removed that class which did nothing (checked in the style inspector), my animation started to work.

Answer (score 0):

see here an example, I do not know what exactly you are doing, this should suffice:

```
$("#mydiv").toggleClass("visible-popup");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y36aer5m/

Comment: Yeah, this is the same as mine, but for some reason, mine is not working. The interesting part is when I toggle it manually in Chrome developer tools, it works perfectly.

Comment: maybe you accidently wrote addClass(".visible-popup") instead of addClass("visible-popup"), wild guess

Comment: checked. nope, `addClass` code is correct. the class is actually being added to the DOM element, I can verify this behavior in inspector.

Comment: then post your code.... how are we supposed to keep guessing what you did wrong :)

Comment: I want to, but it's under NDA, that's why I can't.

Comment: isolate the 3 lines of code involved in this issue, that does not break an NDA

Comment: It's just as the real one in the question. I think I'm starting to pinpoint the issue. this div is inside bootstrap's modal dialog. and it also animates a fader when being displayed, is there a possibility that they are conflicting? If I delay the `addClass` by like 100ms, it works.

Comment: Interesting. my containing div had a class named `fade` which apparently doesn't have any effect at all. When I removed that class which did nothing (checked in the style inspector), my animation started to work.